# decorate or style path between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to draw two “blobs”, and a curve from one blob to the other, which is colored differently between the blobs.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{point/.style={fill,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Blob 1
    \draw[
        name path=blob1,
    ] (0,0) to[closed,
        curve through={(3,3) .. (6.5,0) .. (11,1) .. (13,-2) .. (9, -4 ) .. (3,-2.5)}
    ] (1,-4.5);
    % Blob 2
    \draw[
        name path=blob2,
    ] (5,4) to[closed, curve through={(7,5)}] (7,1);
                % Curve from blob 1 to blob 2
    \draw[
        name path=connector,
    ] (1,-2) node[point,label=A] (A) {}
        to[curve through={(3,0) .. (6,-1)}] (8,3) 
        (8,3) node[point,label=B] (B) {};
    \draw[
        name intersections={of=blob1 and connector,by=exit},
        name intersections={of=blob2 and connector,by=entry},
    ]
        node[point,red,label=exit] at (exit) {}
        node[point,green,label=entry] at (entry) {}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

([view in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pxwpdfvbdvbx))

[image: code output]

What I would like is to color the curve (let's say) green from `A` to `exit`, red from `exit` to `entry`, and then green again from `entry` to `B`.

I looked into decorations to do this, and I think I could do it if I could convert the intersections into positions along the `connector` path.  But I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PGFPlots has `intersection segments` exactly for this.

Here is an alternative solution without additional libraries. The calculated intersections are not needed unless you want to add a point there.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, red] (1,-2) coordinate (A) to[curve through={(3,0) .. (6,-1)}] (8,3) (8,3) coordinate (B);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) to[closed, curve through={(3,3) .. (6.5,0) .. (11,1) .. (13,-2) .. (9, -4 ) .. (3,-2.5)}] (1,-4.5);
\draw[fill=white] (6.7,3) circle[radius=2];
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) to[closed, curve through={(3,3) .. (6.5,0) .. (11,1) .. (13,-2) .. (9, -4 ) .. (3,-2.5)}] (1,-4.5);
\draw[thick, green] (1,-2) to[curve through={(3,0) .. (6,-1)}] (8,3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (6.7,3) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick, blue] (1,-2) to[curve through={(3,0) .. (6,-1)}] (8,3);
\end{scope}
\fill (A) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {A};
\fill (B) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two shapes and a tri colored curve]

Comment: I would recommend to store the different curves in macros to use them afterwards but that's the method I'd use too.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `spath3` library just for this. It allows you to split a path as it intersects any other path, and then get each part as a new path.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3} % for splitting the path 'connector'

\begin{document}
\tikzset{point/.style={fill,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Blob 1
    \draw[
        name path=blob1,
    ] (0,0) to[closed,
        curve through={(3,3) .. (6.5,0) .. (11,1) .. (13,-2) .. (9, -4 ) .. (3,-2.5)}
    ] (1,-4.5);
    % Blob 2
    \draw[
        name path=blob2,
    ] (5,4) to[closed, curve through={(7,5)}] (7,1);
    % Curve from blob 1 to blob 2
    \path[% we create the path, but don't draw it
        name path=connector,
    ] (1,-2) node[point,label=A] (A) {}
        to[curve through={(3,0) .. (6,-1)}] (8,3) 
        (8,3) node[point,label=B] (B) {};
    \tikzset
    {% here we split the path 'connector' and get its components
        spath/split at intersections={connector}{blob1},
        spath/split at intersections={connector}{blob2},
        spath/get components of={connector}\cpts,
    }
    % and then we draw the components separately
    \draw[green,spath/use=\getComponentOf\cpts{1}];
    \draw[red  ,spath/use=\getComponentOf\cpts{2}];
    \draw[green,spath/use=\getComponentOf\cpts{3}];
    \draw[
        name intersections={of=blob1 and connector,by=exit},
        name intersections={of=blob2 and connector,by=entry},
    ]
        node[point,red,label=exit] at (exit) {}
        node[point,green,label=entry] at (entry) {}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the picture:
[image]

Comment: This looks like just the ticket!  `spath3` isn't in the tikz manual so I didn't know about it.

Comment: I have a package called `spath3.sty` but not a TikZ library of that name.  Is it new to TeX-live?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, yes it's new, or so I think. I didn't have it until TL2021, or at least I couldn't compile a code made by Andrew Stacey (its creator) that I found in this site a couple of months ago.